# xmlns attribute causes error with XDocument in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Somehow **xmlns** in `<math xmlns='bla'>` causes error. By changing `xmlns` to e.g. `xmlnss` the error won't occur.
What't the reason and is there a solution?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;                      
public class Program{
        public static void Main(){
            string mathMLResult = @"<math xmlns='bla'>
                            <SnippetCode>
                              testcode1
                            </SnippetCode>
                        </math>";

            XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(mathMLResult);
            XElement mathNode = xml.Descendants("math").FirstOrDefault();

            // error occurres in this line
            List<XNode> childNodes = mathNode.Nodes().ToList();

            XElement mrow = new XElement("mrow");
            mrow.Add(childNodes);
            mathNode.RemoveNodes();
            XElement mstyle = new XElement("mstyle");
            XElement semantics = new XElement("semantics");
            XElement annotation = new XElement("annotation",
            new XAttribute("encoding", "\&quot;application/x-tex\&quot;"));
            semantics.Add(mrow);
            semantics.Add(annotation);
            mstyle.Add(semantics);
            mathNode.Add(mstyle);
            var s = mathNode.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
```

That's what I actually want.

```
  <math xmlns="bla">
  <mstyle>
    <semantics>
      <mrow>
        <SnippetCode>
              testcode1
         </SnippetCode>
      </mrow>
      <annotation encoding="&quot;application/x-tex&quot;" />
    </semantics>
  </mstyle>
</math>
```

Answer (score 0):

T

1. he problem because:  you get  xml.Descendants("math") without
   namespace and the result is always null.
2. This line of code is
       syntax error because of wrong escape character( \ ):

> new XAttribute("encoding", "\"application/x-tex\""));

I already fixed it.  Please take a look:

```
        string mathMLResult = @"<math xmlns='bla'>
                        <SnippetCode>
                          testcode1
                        </SnippetCode>
                    </math>";

        XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(mathMLResult);
        XElement mathNode = xml.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "math");

        // error occurres in this line
        List<XNode> childNodes = mathNode.Nodes().ToList();

        XElement mrow = new XElement("mrow");
        mrow.Add(childNodes);
        mathNode.RemoveNodes();
        XElement mstyle = new XElement("mstyle");
        XElement semantics = new XElement("semantics");
        XElement annotation = new XElement("annotation",
            new XAttribute("encoding", @"\&quot;application/x-tex\&quot;"));
        semantics.Add(mrow);
        semantics.Add(annotation);
        mstyle.Add(semantics);
        mathNode.Add(mstyle);
        var s = mathNode.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Regard!

Comment: Thanks. How to get rid of `xmlns="bla"` in `SnippetCode xmlns="bla"> testcode1</SnippetCode>`?

Comment: Hi, your should include namespace: {namespace}+xmlName. In your case is: xml.Descendants("{bla}" + "math").FirstOrDefault()

Answer (score 0):

xlmns is for namespace but in your case it is just nowhere to found. It is used to find how XML should be read. It could be anything

**xmlns:xsl** -

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

**xmlns:android**

**xmlns:xhtml**

Check here

https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

If you still want to do it try below code, but xml should be right format for this

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XNamespace bla = "bla";
```

I tried the following code it works without giving error

```
string mathMLResult = @"<math xmlns='bla'>
                            <SnippetCode>
                              testcode1
                            </SnippetCode>
                        </math>";

XDocument xmld = XDocument.Parse(mathMLResult);
XNamespace bla = "bla";
var mathItem = xmld.Element(bla + "math");
var SnippetCodeItem = mathItem.Element(bla + "SnippetCode");
```

[image]

Try below code. It may work

```
static XElement stripNS(XElement root)
{
    return new XElement(
        root.Name.LocalName,
        root.HasElements ?
            root.Elements().Select(el => stripNS(el)) :
            (object)root.Value
    );
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string mathMLResult = @"<math xmlns='bla'>
                    <SnippetCode>
                        testcode1
                    </SnippetCode>
                </math>";

    XDocument xmld = XDocument.Parse(mathMLResult);
    XNamespace bla = "bla";
    var mathNode = xmld.Element(bla + "math");
    mathNode = stripNS(mathNode);
    List<XNode> childNodes = mathNode.Nodes().ToList();

    XElement mrow = new XElement("mrow");
    mrow.Add(childNodes);
    mathNode.RemoveNodes();

    XElement mstyle = new XElement("mstyle");
    XElement semantics = new XElement("semantics");
    XElement annotation = new XElement("annotation",
    new XAttribute("encoding", "&quot;application/x-tex&quot;"));
    semantics.Add(mrow);
    semantics.Add(annotation);
    mstyle.Add(semantics);
    mathNode.Add(mstyle);

    var s = mathNode.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: And what if <SnippetCode> is unknown?